# Name for $(1-x)$?

Tags: functions, terminology

The **multiplicative inverse** of $x$ is $\frac{1}{x}$,

and the **additive inverse** of $x$ is $-x$,

is there a similar term for $(1-x)$?

Comment: It is the complement to 1.

Comment: Usually just $(1-x)$.

Comment: What is your $x$? And what is $1$? Are they allowed to be operators?

Comment: By the way, what makes $f(x)=1-x$ interesting is that $f(f(x))=x$, just like for $\frac{1}{x}$ and $-x$.

Comment: @Rasmus: ...and what's the word to describe that property?

Comment: @Richard, it's an [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$1-x$ <strike>is</strike> could be <strike>known</strike> called <strike>as</strike> the "complement to $1$ of $x$".

*Added*: In English this designation is likely not generally used.

But "[one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One%27s_complement)" and "[complementary angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_angles)" are, according to English Wikipedia. In French the "[Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)" is known as "[*Formule des compléments*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formule_des_compl%C3%A9ments)".

*Added* 2: This designation would be more natural for $0\le x\le 1$, similarly to  complementary angles: [*An acute angle is "filled up" by its complement to form a right angle.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_angles)

Comment: Congratulations on 10k reputation!

Comment: @Austin Mohr: Thank you!

Comment: I can accept *complement* but not *is known as*. Any references?

Comment: @lhf: It is a direct translation from the Portuguese/French. I have thought of the "[Formule des compléments"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formule_des_compl%C3%A9ments) $$\forall z\ 0<\text{Re}(z)<1,\Gamma (1-z)\Gamma (z)=\frac{\pi }{\sin \pi z}$$

Comment: Funny that that equation is called [Euler's *reflection* formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) in English... Also funny is that *fórmula de reflexão de Euler* is mentioned in the PT as http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Função_gama. But that probably is just a translation of the EN page.

Comment: @lhf: That's right!

Comment: @lhf: ... and there's the [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One%27s_complement)

Comment: @lhf: ... as well as [complementary angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_angles).

Comment: @lhf *Fórmula de reflexão de Euler* is a more recent Portuguese translation than *fórmula (de Euler) dos complementos*.

Comment: @Ihf: here's a reference http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63987/name-for-1-x/63992#63992 $$$$ :)

Comment: @The Chaz: *I [you] frequently relate to people with (what I [you] think is) humor :)*. Yes, it is!

Comment: Well thanks! And seriously, nomenclature has to start *somewhere*. I'm all in favor of this expression. Or we could call it the "American complement". Ok that last part was not as serious...

Answer (score 10):

I would call it the complement. One motivation is that if some event occurs with probability $p$, the complementary event occurs with probability $1 - p$.

Comment: I agree that I'd call it the complement; the further away from probability one gets, though, the less meaningful this name seems.

Comment: But how many people are far away from probability? z corresponding to $6\sigma$ ?!?

Answer (score 6):

I'd call it a *complement* or a *negation*.  You don't need to stand all that close to probability for these names to seem meaningful, in my opinion.  If we have 0 as indicating falsity, and 1 as indicating truth, then the negation of a proposition x has truth value of (1-x).  The same holds if we have 1 as indicating falsity, and 0 as indicating truth.  In fuzzy logic, which has truth values of the unit interval [0, 1], (1-x) also comes as the fuzzy complement most commonly considered.

Also, consider classical or crisp sets under their characteristic function representation.  The characteristic function assigns 1 to each element of the universal set which belongs to the subset under consideration, and 0 to each element of the universal set which does not belong to the subset under consideration.  For example, if we have {a, b, c, d} as our universal set, and {a, b} as the subset under consideration, the characteristic function assigns 1 to a, 1 to b, 0 to c, and 0 to d, or equivalently
{(a, 1), (b, 1), (c, 0), (d, 0)}.  Now, *the complement* of {a, b} for this universal set equals {c, d}.  Well, (1-x) on the values defined by the characteristic function for 
{a, b}={(a, 1), (b, 1), (c, 0), (d, 0)} gives us {(a, 0), (b, 0), (c, 1), (d, 1)}={c, d} the complement of {a, b}.  This does generalize also such that (1-x) here always gives us the complement of the subset under consideration.